# UWP ProgressRing is shown with big lag during data loading in background

Tags: c#, gridview, uwp, progress-bar

I'm using UWP `GridView` with `DataTemplateSelector` to show data for different weeks. When I change the week I want to show loader when data is loading. I'm using MvvmLight for ViewModels binding and when I change the data I'm removing and adding elements to the `GridView` source. The problem is that when I change `IsActive` property to true before I run `UpdateGrid` method, the loader is not active and there is a lag on screen. If data loading (`UpdateGrid` method) takes more than one sec the loader is visible, so it means for me that the logic there is ok, but the problem can be with generating graphical elements on the screen and performance?

I was trying to make my `UpdateGrid` method async and sync (there is no api call inside, so can be sync). The method is called in the ViewModel class:

```
DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(async () =>
     {
        SyncLoadingImageVisible = true;
        await UpdateGrid();
        SyncLoadingImageVisible = false;
     });
```

Comment: It would also be helpful if you posted the code of `UpdateGrid` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be misunderstanding the way `async/await` works. When you mark a method `async` ans it contains no **real** await (meaning no I/O bound operation or operation that actually takes place on another thread), the whole method will essentially run synchronously. This is true in your case as well as you mentioned there is no actual async work inside `UpdateGrid` so the code will work as if there was really no `await`.

The UI thread will be busy all the time from the moment you set the `SyncLoadingImageVisible` to `true` to the moment you set it back to `false` - during that time UI thread is 100% dedicated to executing your code so user won't see any UI changes. This causes the behavior you are seeing - that there is a lag as the UI thread does not have a chance to update the UI until the `UpdateGrid` method finishes executing.

To solve this properly you will have to offload performance intensive, non-UI tasks in `UpdateGrid` method to another thread using awaited `Task.Run` and only the code that really does work with the app's UI should then be executed on UI thread. This way you will free the UI thread to be able to display progress to the user while the execution runs in the background.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I created separated async method to get my data and then I call UpdateGrid just to assing new values to ViewModel and it works great!

`DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(async () =>`
            `{`
                `SyncLoadingImageVisible = true;`
                `var data = await GetData();`
                `SyncLoadingImageVisible = false;`
                `UpdateGrid();`
`});`

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped :-)